# ui-sref for anchor tag unable to click

Tags: angularjs

when I set ui-sref for anchor tag is unable to click but it will work well when I replaced with href attribute

```
            <table>
               <tr>
                <td class="sideMenu">
                    <a ui-sref="#/Home">Home</a>
                    <a ui-sref="#/Course">Course</a>
                    <a ui-sref="#/Student">Student</a>
                </td>
                <td class="mainMenu">
                    <ui-view></ui-view>
                </td>
            </tr>
                        </table>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

when I set ui-sref for anchor tag is unable to click but it will work well when I replaced with href attribute
  and  this is my angularjs code

```
/// <reference path="angular-1.7.8/angular.js" />
/// <reference path="angular-1.7.8/angular-route.js" />

var myApp = angular
    .module('myModule', ['ui.router'])
    .config(function ($stateProvider,$urlRouteProvider) {
        $stateProvider
            .state('Home', {
                url: '/Home',
                templateUrl: 'Template43/Home.html',
                controller: 'homeController',
                controllerAs: 'homeCtr'
            })
            .state('Course', {
                url: '/Course',
                templateUrl: 'Template43/Course.html',
                controller: 'courseController',
                controllerAs: 'courseCtr'
            })
            .state('Student', {
                url: '/Student',
                templateUrl: 'Template43/Student.html',
                controller: 'studentController',
                controllerAs: 'studentCtr',
                resolve: {
                    studentList: function ($http) {
                        return $http.get('WebService43RouteUi.asmx/getData')
                            .then(function (response) {
                                return response.data;
                            });
                    }
                }
            });
        $locationProvider.hashPrefix('');
    })
```

Answer (score 0):

You need `angular-ui-router.js` for `ui-router`, not `angular-route.js`.

In the HTML, replace `#/Home` with `Home`.

In the Javascript replace `url: '/Home'` with `url: '#/Home'`.

Comment: I am using angular-ui-router.js in html code on script tag it does not woking

Comment: You also don't need `#/Home` just `Home`.

Comment: when removed # but even it does not work

Comment: but I previously worked with href but it work well

Comment: Did you remove `#` and `/`? Try removing this `$locationProvider.hashPrefix('');` and angular-route.js reference.

Comment: I got answer just I have change my url and I posted the answer also it working well now but even if I provide $locationProvider.hashPrefix('') with parameter for config

Comment: Updated my answer to include the # added to URL.

Answer (score 0):

This code works correctly.

**HTML:**

```
 <tr>
    <td class="sideMenu">
        <a ui-sref="Home">Home</a>
        <a ui-sref="Course">Course</a>
        <a ui-sref="Student">Student</a>
    </td>
    <td class="mainMenu">
        <ui-view></ui-view>
    </td>
</tr>
```

**script.js:**

```
/// <reference path="angular-1.7.8/angular.js" />

var myApp = angular
    .module('myModule', ['ui.router'])
    .config(function ($stateProvider) {
        $stateProvider
            .state('Home', {
                url: '#/Home',
                templateUrl: 'Template43/Home.html',
                controller: 'homeController',
                controllerAs: 'homeCtr'
            })
            .state('Course', {
                url: '#/Course',
                templateUrl: 'Template43/Course.html',
                controller: 'courseController',
                controllerAs: 'courseCtr'
            })
            .state('Student', {
                url: '#/Student',
                templateUrl: 'Template43/Student.html',
                controller: 'studentController',
                controllerAs: 'studentCtr',
                resolve: {
                    studentList: function ($http) {
                        return $http.get('WebService43RouteUi.asmx/getData')
                            .then(function (response) {
                                return response.data;
                            });
                    }
                }
            });
    })
```